# (Client Authentication) Add ssl client certificate to smart device

Tags: android, ios, nginx, webserver, ssl-certificate

I'm setup nginx web server to SSL client authentication and I want to use the website by smart phone (iOS, android). But not work. The smart device cannot import client certification into web browser such as iOS > Safari, android > google chrome.

Help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most secure method, but one way to get the client certificate installed on a mobile device is to:

- Create a PKCS#12 file with a password using `openssl`:

  cat user.key user.crt | openssl pkcs12 -export -out user.p12
- Send the `user.p12` file to the device (e.g. over a secure email connection)
- Install it (e.g. by opening the attachment).

On the iPhone, the certificate will appear under: Settings → General → Profiles

Comment: Thank you for answer, If I SSL client authentication to android device?.